# The last card of the recycler view inside the fragment does not show and my recycler view is not able to handle Large Data

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm currently faced with two different issues.

1) The Last Card of my recycler View is not at all Visible.

(I've embedded my RecyclerView inside a relative layout ).

The purpose of the layout is to populate the view of a fragment inside a CoordinatorLayout. (I've used Tabs, and this is the layout of one of the tabs).

Here's my XML file:

```
  <RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rlv"
    tools:context=".TwoFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />                   
</RelativeLayout>
```

2) The second problem I'm faced with is that my RecyclerView is not able to handle large data sets (I've used a custom Adapter). It keeps crashing.

As long as I put 10 Objects it works fine. When the ObjectList contains 30 elements or more it keeps crashing.

This is My Custom Adapter for The Recycler View

public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<Contact> contactList;

public ContactAdapter(List<Contact> contactList) {
    this.contactList = contactList;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, int i) {
    Contact ci = contactList.get(i);
    contactViewHolder.contactName.setText(ci.getContactName());
    contactViewHolder.uniteName.setText(ci.getUniteName());
    contactViewHolder.status.setText(ci.getStatus());
    contactViewHolder.lastUpdated.setText(ci.getLastUpdated());
    contactViewHolder.contactPicture.setImageBitmap(ci.getContactPicture());
}
@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.list_row, viewGroup, false);


    return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
}

public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    protected TextView contactName;
    protected TextView uniteName;
    protected TextView status;
    protected TextView lastUpdated;
    protected CircleImageView contactPicture;

    public ContactViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        contactName =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        uniteName = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        status = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        lastUpdated = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);
        contactPicture = (CircleImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    }

}
```

}

The problem is completely weird! I'd be very very very very glad if someone could help me out!!

Comment: 30 elements is not an large data what are you doing with that data in view that the matter post your adapter

Comment: Could you post some code from your custom adapter?

Comment: I've added my custom adapter! It works good as long as i put a small number of objects in the contactList.. But when the collection gets bigger ( from 25 onwards) It begins to crash.. Please help!!

Comment: yeah sure @RichardG and pavan

Comment: I just solved it! Thanks for showing intrest @RichardG and pavan. :)